# LibreOffice Tree with columns

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org, uno, libreoffice-basic, pyuno

I am writing an extension for LibreOffifce.
A tree with columns on my sidebar is needed. (example - https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html)

I found information about Tree Control and module "tree", e.g. here
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Treecontrol
https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/awt/tree/module-ix.html

But I couldn't find anything about writing a **tree with columns**.

There is a quote "You can provide your own model which must at least support the interface com.sun.star.awt.XTreeModel." in the  article "Tree control", but I also couldn't find any information about providing of my own models...

Please, help me find information and examples, if it is possible to provide tree with columns for LibreOffice extension.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Python-UNO code (as tagged in your question) that shows how to implement the `XTreeDataModel` UNO interface. You'll have to write a lot more code in order to render the nodes in multiple columns and do everything else you want. It may be required to create another class that implements `XTreeNode`.

```py
import uno
import unohelper
from com.sun.star.awt.tree import XTreeDataModel

def myTree():
    document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    ctx = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getComponentContext()
    smgr = ctx.getServiceManager()
    dlgprov = smgr.createInstanceWithArgumentsAndContext(
        "com.sun.star.awt.DialogProvider", (document,), ctx)
    dlg = dlgprov.createDialog(
        "vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Dialog1?location=application")

    treeCtrl = dlg.getControl("TreeControl1")
    treeModel = treeCtrl.getModel()
    mutableTreeDataModel = smgr.createInstanceWithContext(
        "com.sun.star.awt.tree.MutableTreeDataModel", ctx)
    rootNode = mutableTreeDataModel.createNode("Root", True)  
    mutableTreeDataModel.setRoot(rootNode)
    myTree = MyTreeDataModel(rootNode)
    model = mutableTreeDataModel

    childNode1 = model.createNode("Parent 1", True)
    rootNode.appendChild(childNode1)   
    subChildNode = model.createNode("Child 1", True)
    childNode1.appendChild(subChildNode)

    treeModel.setPropertyValue("DataModel", myTree)
    dlg.execute()
    dlg.dispose()

class MyTreeDataModel(unohelper.Base, XTreeDataModel):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.rootNode = root
  
    def getRoot(self):
        return self.rootNode

    def addTreeDataModelListener(self, listener):
        pass

    def removeTreeDataModelListener(self, listener):
        pass
```

More information for working with trees is at https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Going_further_with_Dialog_and_Component#The_New_Tree_Control.

If it turns out that there is no convenient way to do this directly with UNO, I once did this with a JTreeTable in Java. LibreOffice extensions can be written in Java, so perhaps that would solve your needs instead.